# Dont allow multiple tabs in same browser

Tags: asp.net, browser

How can i allow multiple tab browser sessions?  I've done research and found this line of code:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="UseUri" />
```

I was not allowed to use this because the url was displaying the session id on every tab.  Are there any other way else i can allow unique session id in multiple tabs?  Does any other state managements available is able to work in multiple tabs?

Comment: From your included snippet, this appears to be an ASP.NET question; tagging it thus.

Comment: Assuming it relates to your other question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740289/can-we-store-viewstate-in-masterpage ), this doesn't solves your problem. Windows can still be duplicated (ie, `Ctrl+N`), and various other actions can break your schema.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Whatever session method you're using, it will still be possible to get the same session into multiple tabs, and impossible to detect on the serverside that a page has been opened in a new tab.

Regardless of whether you're allowed to use it or not, the UseUri session management method won't help. If a user tries to open a link in a new tab rather than in the current window, you [a] have no way of detecting this on the server-side, and [b] you have no way on the server-side to create a new session, transfer the page execution to this new session, all whilst keeping the current session intact.